# Meshgrid of an arbitrary domain in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I need to evaluate a function in a complicated domain and only in this domain. There are values outside of it but I don't want them plotted. I don't know how to create a proper `meshgrid` to do so.

There's a picture of the domain I am talking about down here:

[image]

Comment: How do you want to sample the domain? Using a rectangular grid or a radial grid?

Comment: @CrisLuengo radial, same origin as the picture.

Comment: do you have an analytic expression that set this domain? or something ?

Comment: @bla I think r should follow the following inequality b < r < 2.a.cos( θ )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about:

```
[x, y]=meshgrid(linspace(0,10,1000),linspace(-5,5,1000));
r=sqrt(x.^2+y.^2);
theta=atan2(y,x);

a=4;
b=1;

I = r<2*a*cos(theta) & theta<pi/2 & theta>-pi/2 & r>b; % this is what you want

imagesc([0 10],[-5 5],I)
```

[image]

So `I` is a matrix of `1` in the domain and `0` outside, based on the logical conditions set in the question.... I chose some arbitrary values of `a`,`b`, etc to demonstrate it in a plot...

Comment: But, how could I use this? I need to plot stresses in the domain that you have just found. Let's say I have the function `stress(r,theta)`. I need to plot a `contour` of stress in this domain only. How do I use this logical mask?

Comment: edit the question with a minimal example ... you have the def or r and theta... `I` is a mask you can multiply by etc...

Comment: @Gadorcha, calculate your expression on the full domain first (ex:`v=f(x,y);`, or `v=f(r,theta)` if using cylindrical coordinates), then mask the unwanted values by converting them to NaN => `v(~I) = NaN`. This way all the values outside of the domain `I` won't be plotted.